# Include form from another page in Orbeon Form Builder

Tags: orbeon

I am using Orbeon Form Builder to build our portal forms. Can I create small forms (eg. 1 form for each section) and then create 1 big form with each of the small sections in Form Builder? I have multiple forms with the some sets of questions that are the same. I am trying to reduce redundancy and create modular forms that can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

The Form Builder [section templates](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide#TOC-Section-templates) might solve this one for you. In essence, they allow you, in a special form, to create sections that can then be reused in other forms.

Comment: @Sonal, excellent. And if this answer works for you, don't forget to mark it as "correct" by clicking on the green marker to the left of the answer.